# Javascript tab character removal

Tags: javascript, regex, string, parsing, web

I need to remove tab characters within text inputted into particular fields of a web interface.  The problem seems to be that when this happens the resulting text now contains spaces where the tabs were.

I tried using the regex : `vVal = vVal.replace(/(\s+)/, "");`  but using the example input `11111[tab]`, the value becomes `11111[space]`.

I dont know how this could be..

Comment: Your regex should completely remove all space characters (including tabs) from the string.

Comment: Not a JS person, but What does `vVar = "\t\t\t".replace(/\t+/g);` assign to vVar?

Comment: @sln, just from testing in my console it would appear, since you didn't specify the 2nd param it is undefined. So it replaces the `\t+` with `String(undefined)`. So it literally assigns the string `"undefined"`. `'hi'.replace('i') -> 'hundefined'`

Comment: @OGHaza - Oh sorry, forgot the replacement parameter. What would `vVar = "\t\t\t".replace(/\t+/g, "");` assign to vVar?

Comment: @sln - haha, ah right. In that case `/\t+/` will match 1 or more `\t` - so it matches the entire `\t\t\t` and replaces it with an empty string, leaving vVar as an empty string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\s` matches any whitespace that includes space also.

For tab try `\t` with global switch:

```
vVal = vVal.replace(/\t+/g, "");
```

Comment: @Downvoter: Please leave a comment for my education.

Comment: I was sure [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057233/javascript-tab-character-removal#comment29875296_20057233) was enough for you. If not here is some evidence that your solution doesn't make any sense at all: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-white-space.

Comment: Sorry I am not getting you. OP wants to remove only tabs not all white-spaces and that is that I answered.

Comment: Not really. Just read the question carefully: *The problem seems to be that when this happens the resulting text now contains spaces where the tabs were*. So according to this (and the examples from the question), the OP for some reason gets tabs replaced with spaces.

Comment: I can't read OP's mind but question title says otherwise and OP starts with this `I need to remove tab characters within text`

Comment: Very often title is not enough to get the context of the question. You have rather high reputation, you should know it. Posting the answer right after reading the title is not too professional IMO.

Comment: @VisioN - Tell me why removing tabs is not the solution?

Comment: @VisioN: IMO you also have very high reputation should not pick the unnecessary battle when fault lies in the question (not just title very first statement says same `I need to remove tab characters within text`).

Comment: @anubhava If you consider the question unclear you should better post a comment rather than a possibly wrong answer. To my perceptions your answer does not actually answer the question and looks more like the way to display potentially unrelated information.

Comment: @VisioN: Too be honest before your comments, question didn't look confusing to me since title and first sentence mean same. Of course OP's example doesn't make much sense and I suspect OP has some other issue with the original input.

Comment: The way I see it, this is the solution to the OP's problem - but the OP didn't ask for the solution, he asked for help. Not that I have a problem with this answer. $.02

Comment: @anubhava Well, for me the question is either written incorrectly, or the problem is in the wrong code behind it which forces the user input to replace tabs with spaces instead of removing them. I will revert my downvote back keeping in mind that you were confused with the question description as many others here.

Comment: @VisioN: Thanks and I am only waiting for OP's comment so that I can modify or delete my answer (if I'm totally off-track).